# what does the "modules:auto" means in @babel/preset-env field?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, babel-preset-env

the babel docs say the modules default option is auto, what does the auto means? does it transform the "import" to "require" or not? what's the difference between "modules: false" and "modules: auto"? it seems they are the same result; I'm learning tree shaking, when I didn't set any options to my @babel/preset-env, tree shaking success, when I set "modules: false", the tree shaking also succeed;

```js
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",{"modules": "false"}
    ]
  ],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` means `default value` and default value of `modules` is `false`.  See - https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/8485/files#r236086742.

```
`Invalid Option: The 'modules' option must be one of \n` +
  ` - 'false' to indicate no module processing\n` +
  ` - a specific module type: 'commonjs', 'amd', 'umd', 'systemjs'` +
  ` - 'auto' (default) which will automatically select 'false' if the current\n` +
  `   process is known to support ES module syntax, or "commonjs" otherwise\n`,
```

Answer (score 8):

It seems that the documentation for *auto* is described in [this](https://github.com/babel/website/pull/1856) pull request. According to that PR:

> The default `auto` will automatically select `false` if ES6 module syntax is already supported by the caller, or `"commonjs"` otherwise.

So, if ES6 is supported (which seems to be your case) setting modules to *auto* its the same as setting *false*.