# Although i write "type" : "module" in package.json, i still get "Cannot use import statement outside a module" error

Tags: javascript, babeljs

I'm working on a exercise react project and i got an error i couldn't fix still. I tried so many ways and didn't work.

This is app.js:

```
import {AddJob} from './Comps/AddJob.js'
import {JobList} from "./Comps/JobList.js"
import {DoneJobs} from "./Comps/DoneJobs.js"



function App() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="row justify-content-center">
                <div className="col">
                    <AddJob />
                </div>
                <div className="col">
                    <JobList />
                </div>
                <div className="col">
                    <DoneJobs />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "react-starter-kit",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "npx babel src/app.js --out-file=public/scripts/app.js --watch"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
    "@babel/register": "^7.22.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/standalone": "^7.22.10",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcrFc.png)

.babelrc:

`{ "presets": [["@babel/preset-env",{ "modules": false }],"@babel/preset-react"] }`

I tried to write `"type":"module"` in package.json, i expected to work it but it didn't.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55792651/1377002 - try removing `{"modules": false }` from that presets line.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Andy When i remove `{"modules": false }` ,  i get "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at app.js:3:15 " error. 

@MikeWeiss i get https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcrFc.png

Comment: Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58211880/uncaught-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module-when-import. I'm guessing you need to remove that modules: false bit and then make sure you don't have anywhere in your app using the "require" way of importing things. Can you check for that and then let us know if you find anything?

Comment: @MikeWeiss i created a project with `npx create-react-app` and there is no error anymore. Thank you and @Andy .