# Error - Add @babel/preset-react to the 'presets' section of your Babel config

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am getting below error when trying to add JSX in a js file

```
Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (9:9):
Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.
```

I tried adding below in package.json

```
"babel": {
        "presets": [
            "@babel/react",
            "@babel/env"
        ],
        "plugins": [
            "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
            "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime"
        ]
    }
```

But still getting the same error.

Earlier, I had also tried adding .babelrc as below. But even that did not work

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
}
```

Is there something specific to be added to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this config in `.babelrc` file. The `modules: false` reason can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55792519/what-does-the-modulesauto-means-in-babel-preset-env-field)

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "modules": false
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```